# Using AWS Lambda to periodically monitor state of a remote resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I need to implement the following feature in the backend on AWS:
- API endpoint which allows a user to start a particular long running "process" in a remote system
- the process status in this remote system should be monitored periodically (every few-several seconds) for status and when status == complete, trigger an action (the remote system does not support sending/triggering notifications or callbacks)

We use primarily lambda functions so I'm thinking about approaching it in the following way:
- my endpoint which is triggered by the user would call remote system to start the process, store record in internal DB and generate a message to SQS (with a delivery delay of X seconds)
- there would be a second lambda that would read messages from SQS & check status of the process in this remote system. When status == complete, trigger an action, when status != complete, generate another message to SQS which would again the same lambda would pick up after X seconds of delay and repeat the check and so on

I'm wondering if there is a better solution/tools to implement this kind of monitoring/notification pattern in the AWS since I'm not that familiar with all the services that AWS provides.

Would anyone comment on this approach and perhaps suggest an alternative if there is one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) which I think is the best fit for your use case.

All you need to do is, instead of generating a SQS message, initiate an execution of a StateMachine in StepFunctions.

The following tutorial explains a iterator loop with a counter. But you can use the same logic to check the status and keep looping until status == complete

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html

Another useful resource which I think very close to your use case
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-project-job-poller.html

Comment: Brilliant, there is even an example which looks very similar to what I have to do: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-project-job-poller.html